# From forward declaration and conditional compilation to what?

Tags: c++, gcc

I have a `Container` class, which has been designed with an item type, declared in the header and conditionally defined in the cpp-file:

Container.h:

```
struct Container
{
  Container();
  // other members
private:
  struct ITEM;
  ITEM* table;
};
```

Container.cpp:

```
#include "Container.h"

#if CONTAINER_TYPE == 1

struct Container::ITEM
{
  // some data fields
};

#elif CONTAINER_TYPE == 2

struct Container::ITEM
{
  // some data fields
};

#else
#error "..."
#endif

Container::Container()
{
  table = new ITEM[100];
}
```

Now I want to get rid of conditional compilation, and instead to use some combination of templates and inheritance to choose the item type during the `Container` construction:

```
// main.cpp
#include "Container.h"

int main()
{
  Container c(1);
  // and so on
}
```

My requirements:

- The `ITEM` type shouldn't contain `vtable`, cause the `ITEM` size and performance are extremely important - I'm talking about really large containers.
- The template mechanics should begin and end in the cpp-file, cause I don't want to disclose too much know-how to customers - only headers will be accessible to them.

What are my options? Are there any design patterns, applicable here?

Comment: Look up "pimpl idiom", put all the private mechanics in the pimpl

Comment: @M.M - it'd be nice if I could define the `impl` pointer to "templatized" structure, but I can't

Comment: So in your current code, you can only have one kind of container in the entire program? That is *weird*. And stupid.

Comment: Don't give the user a container. Give them a handle for a container and hide everything but a couple container access function prototypes in the implementation files.

Comment: @immibis - I have one *weird* container, which I want to supply to my customers, without sources, cause they (customers and sources) aren't stupid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the user of the container to decide the type of item used at runtime, while still hiding the implementation details, you will have to do something more like this:

```
struct Container
{
  enum ItemType { eItemType1, eItemType2 };

  Container(ItemType aItemType);
  ~Container();

  // other members

private:
  struct ITEM {
    virtual ~ITEM() {}
  };
  ITEM** table;
};
```

```
#include "Container.h"

struct ItemType1 : Container::ITEM
{
  // some data fields
};

struct ItemType2 : Container::ITEM
{
  // some data fields
};

Container::Container(Container::ItemType aItemType)
{
  table = new ITEM*[100];

  for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
  {
    switch (aItemType)
    {
      case eItemType1:
        table[i] = new ItemType1;
        break;

      case eItemType2:
        table[i] = new ItemType2;
        break;

      default:
        table[i] = new ITEM;
        break;
  }
}

Container::~Container()
{
  for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
    delete table[i];
  delete[] table;
}
```

```
#include "Container.h"

int main()
{
  Container c(eItemType1);
  // and so on
}
```

If you absolutely cannot have a vtable in `ITEM`, and the table content must be held in sequential memory, then you will have to do something more like this instead:

```
struct Container
{
  enum ItemType { ItemType1, ItemType2 };

  Container(ItemType aItemType);
  ~Container();

  // other members

private:
  void* table;
  ItemType type;
};
```

```
#include "Container.h"

struct ItemType1
{
  // some data fields
};

struct ItemType2
{
  // some data fields
};

Container::Container(Container::ItemType aItemType)
{
  type = aItemType;

  switch (aItemType)
  {
      case eItemType1:
        table = new ItemType1[100];
        break;

      case type2:
        table = new ItemType2[100];
        break;

      default:
        table = NULL;
        break;
  }
}

Container::~Container()
{
  switch (type)
  {
      case eItemType1:
        delete[] static_cast<ItemType1*>(table);
        break;

      case type2:
        delete[] static_cast<ItemType2*>(table);
        break;
  }
}
```

```
#include "Container.h"

int main()
{
  Container c(eItemType1);
  // and so on
}
```

Comment: The option #2 looks good, however I'll need to have a `switch (type)` in each member function, right?

Comment: @HEKTO yes, you would have to do that

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you have many options if you want to hide the template semantics from your customers. Using templates is easy though. If you wanted to have the data type of the stored data as template arguments it could look something like this:

```
template <typename ITEM>
struct Container
{
    Container(ITEM a) {
        //not sure what you want to do here
        table = new ITEM[100];
    }
    // other members
private:
    //the pointer to the stored array
    ITEM* table;
};

int main()
{
    Container<int>(1);
}
```

Notice that the only thing I did was to make ITEM a template argument. Now you can define which type of data your Container should have when you create an instance of it.

Furthermore if you are looking at performance I don't see why you wouldn't just use a pointer to the data. This way you keep the overhead low and the elements don't get copied each time you copy the container object.

Might not be the best solution but you could start with that. Let me know what you had in mind.

Comment: I can send only a header and compiled library to users, so this approach won't work for me - thanks!

Comment: You could still build a library out of this and pass the header to the customers but maybe I'm misunderstanding something.

Comment: @ThunderStorm: it sounds like the implementation of the library will be precompiled and distributed as a binary, with a header to interact with it.  In which case, using templates doesn't work.

Comment: @RemyLebeau ok, got it.